# функция возвращает не правильное значение

Tags: java

пробую в java android нарисовать спрайт. спрайт загружается из assets и имеет вид файла данных, а не картинку. в этом файле сначала идет int width, потом int height, потом int max_pixels. Если в си программе считать с помощью `fread ( &max_pixels, sizeof ( int ), 1, fp );` так как в java так нельзя делать, я выделил четыре байта для каждой величины, считал их, и перевел с помощью функции get_num в число. и проблема в том что android считывает smax_pixels и возвращает 192, а надо 85440. я посмотрел в hex значениях и оказывается что число 85440 имеет значение `14dc0`, а 192 имеет значение `c0`. такое впечатление будто число обрубается. значит что-то в коде не так, но что?

```
private int get_num ( byte[] n ) {
    int num = 0;
    num |= n[0] <<  0 & 0xff;
    num |= n[1] <<  8 & 0xff;
    num |= n[2] << 16 & 0xff;
    num |= n[3] << 24 & 0xff;
    return num;
}

public void load_sprite ( String path ) {


    byte[] swidth = new byte[4];
    byte[] sheight = new byte[4];
    byte[] smax_pixel = new byte[4];

    try {
        InputStream input = activity.getAssets().open("models/" + path);
        input.read ( swidth );
        input.read ( sheight );
        input.read ( smax_pixel );

        width = get_num(swidth);
        height = get_num(sheight);
        max_pixels = get_num(smax_pixel);

        max_pixels = 85440;
        data = new byte[max_pixels];
        input.read(data);
        input.close();
    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо get_num сделать такой.

```
int get_num ( byte[] n ) {
  int num = 0;
  num |= ( n[0] & 0xff ) <<  0;
  num |= ( n[1] & 0xff ) <<  8;
  num |= ( n[2] & 0xff ) << 16;
  num |= ( n[3] & 0xff ) << 24;
  return num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то, что вы хотите сделать, то метод `get_num` должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private static int get_num(byte[] n) {
    int num = 0;
    num |= 0x00_00_00_FF & n[0];
    num |= 0x00_00_FF_00 & (n[1] << 8);
    num |= 0x00_FF_00_00 & (n[2] << 16);
    num |= 0xFF_00_00_00 & (n[3] << 24);
    return num;
}
```

**Пояснение:**

Скобки перед оператором `<<` (*Signed left shift*) можно опустить (оставил их для наглядности), т.к. он имеет более высокий приоритет, чем оператор `&` (*Bitwise AND*) (см [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)).

В рамках данного примера решения происходит [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) (неявное распространение примитивов) `byte` `->` `int` при использовании оператора `<<`, поэтому для избежания ситуаций распространения ненулевого старшего бита экземпляра `byte` на все более старшие биты получаемого экземпляра `int` (например, `0b1000_0000` -> `0b11...1_0000_0000`, а нам нужно `0b00...1_0000_0000`).

В первой строчке оператор `<<` опущен в виду избыточности, поэтому распространение происходит за счет использования оператора `&`, одним из операндов которого является литерал типа `int`.

**Рекомендации:**

В рамках java для наименования методов согласно [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) принято использовать стиль *camelCase* (`getNum`), а не *snake_case*, как у вас (`get_num`).

Comment: а мне нравиться snake_case, потому что я ещё на си пишу и привык к этому.

Comment: кстати, у вас не правильный пример. я так пробывал, возвращает неправильные значения. надо делать с 0&ff.

Comment: @xverizex, просто в java существует [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), который, как бы, является рекомендацией для наименования сущностей в Java.

Comment: @xverizex, точно, я перепроверил, вы правы, только это касается не только нулевого байта, а любого, т.к. у них в старшем бите может находиться `1`, которая при [арифметическом распространении типов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) byte -> int превратится во множестве 1 в более старших битах в int. Подправил ответ с учетом этой особенности.

Comment: @xverizex, дополнил свой ответ. Кстати, ваш ответ ниже выглядит симпатичнее: я сначала распространяю byte до int за счет сдвига, а потом зануляю лишние биты, а вы, наоборот, зануляете во время распространения, а затем только сдвигаете (с точки зрения количества операций одно и тоже, но они в другом, более удобном, порядке).

Answer (score 1):

```
private int get_num(byte[] n) {
  return (((((n[3] & 0xFF << 8) | n[2] & 0xFF) << 8) | n[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | n[0] & 0xFF;
}
```